# Find all critical points of the function $f(x, y) =\vert x\vert + (x−1)^2−y^2$. Classify them using the second derivative test.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

this is what I have so far:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} = x/\vert x\vert+2(x-1)=0$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y} = -2y=0$$

$y=0$

$x=2$ or $\vert x\vert = 1/2$

What do I do with $\vert x\vert$? Am I on the right track?

Thanks

Comment: Use a case analysis, $x\lessgtr0$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: OP didn't say $f(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Please edit your question using MathJax to write math correctly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ok thanks! Is the correct answer (.5, 0) and (1.5, 0)??

Comment: Write

$$f(x,y)=\pm x+(x-1)^2-y^2=\left(x\pm\frac12-1\right)^2-y^2-\frac14$$

which describes two hyperbolic paraboloids of vertex $(\frac12,0)$ and $(\frac32,0)$. But   $|x|=x$ only holds in the positives, and the only solution is $(\frac12,0)$, a saddle point.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Consider $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2}+(x-1)^2-y^2$ then

$$
\nabla^2 f = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The second derivatives are constant (except along $x=0$ where the function is not differentiable):

$$f_{xx}=2,f_{xy}=0,f_{yy}=-2.$$

As $\Delta<0$, you can conclude about the type.